# in jquery dragable, with revert the item doesn't return to it's start position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I use jquery-ui dragable and set revert option to invalid.

the problem is when i drag an item  and drop it an invalid position it doesn't return to its start position. it take place in new position.

I include the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zMxJv/

Comment: Are you just using this to sort items in a list? If so, you should really think about a `sortable` http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Comment: I use also sortable and dropable.. the problem in dragable i think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `draggable`s and the `droppable` from the code -- you don't actually need them since sortable handles that for you.

Here's an updated fiddle to give you an idea of where this heads: http://jsfiddle.net/zMxJv/5/

If you only want each individual day sortable without cross pollination from other days, remove the `connectWith` property.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the option **revert** takes the values **true** and **false** only, **invalid** and **valid** is available on droppable, you're using draggable.

To solve your problem there is two options, both using sortable and last one also droppable. First one is with the option:

```
containment: 'parent'
```

That will not even allow you to drag an element outside the container.

The other option requires more code. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/qMdGs/3/

**UPDATE:** http://jsfiddle.net/qMdGs/5/

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem... please check example I update it.

Comment: Ok then I have no idea. My solution does this:
1. You can sort all elements in the container
2. If you drop a sortable outside the container it goes back to its original position.

If this isn't what you want, please explain what's wrong and how you want it. Your example doesn't say anything.

Comment: I should also say that my code isn't the final code, I didn't take your html, classes etc..I just showed you how it works, the rest is up to you.

Comment: I think the problem occurred when have multiple droppable

Comment: Oh ok I see it know. I've updated it again, see if it works as you want it to.